# Slack notifications and other sounds freeze the desktop

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, freeze

Ubuntu 18.04.03.  5.0.0-31-generic #33~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP
    Tue Oct 1 10:20:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Whenever I receive a sound-playing notification from Slack, my whole desktop freezes until after the sound is played.

However, I've now proven the problem isn't with Slack, but Ubuntu itself.

Here's a simple test case.  Run this in a terminal:

```
sleep 2 ; while true ; do echo -n '^G' ; sleep 1 ; done
```

where ^G is the bell character and you can enter it with the keystroke Ctrl-V Ctrl-G.

As soon as you enter the command, start moving any window around.

After the 2 second delay your desktop freezes, and then the first sound plays, and the desktop un-freezes.

It continues to be un-frozen.

Ctrl-C in the terminal to stop the repeating sound.

If you now wait for around 20 seconds you can repeat the test.

The problem happens briefly when I choose my laptop built-in speakers, but is *much* worse when I choose audio through HDMI/Displayport.

I have all the latest packages installed.

Any thoughts?

regards,
Russ

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem on my Mac Pro 4,1 (with 5,1 firmware.) Searched everywhere and finally gave up and disabled sound entirely, because it felt like my computer would randomly hang - even though it was just something playing a sound.

This page had a fix that worked for me - all the way at the bottom:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2313164

The only other thing I did (and I'm not sure if it helped) was that I change the config so that PulseAudio could not have high priority:

In `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`:

- Uncomment the line `high-priority = yes`
- Change the value to `no`